# I can't pass the tests Build a 25 + 5 Clock

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you tell me why Timer tests starting from 9 fail?

I can't figure out what's going wrong in the tests.

Everything seems to be working, you can see for yourself:
https://codepen.io/lickoneyou/pen/WNLBQoY

Test name: 25 + 5 Clock

Link to the challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-development-libraries/front-end-development-libraries-projects/build-a-25--5-clock

```
javaScript.js

import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom/client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "https://esm.sh/react";

const App = () => {
  const [breakSession, setBreakSession] = useState("Session");
  const [breakState, setBreakState] = useState(5);
  const [sessionState, setSessionState] = useState(25);
  const [timeSecState, setTimeSecState] = useState(0);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(sessionState);
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  const reset = () => {
    setBreakState(5);
    setSessionState(25);
    setTimeSecState(0);
    setTime(25);
    setPaused(!paused);
    setBreakSession("Session");
  };

  const tick = () => {
    if (!paused) return;

    if (timeSecState === 0 && time === 0 && breakSession === "Session") {
      setBreakSession("Break");
      setTime(breakState);
      setTimeSecState(0);
      return;
    }
    if (timeSecState === 0 && time === 0 && breakSession === "Break") {
      setBreakSession("Session");
      setTime(sessionState);
      setTimeSecState(0);
      return;
    } else if (timeSecState == 0 && time > 0) {
      setTime((state) => (state > 0 ? (state -= 1) : (state = 0)));
      setTimeSecState(59);
      return;
    } else if (timeSecState > 0) {
      setTimeSecState((state) => (state > 0 ? (state -= 1) : (state = 0)));
      return;
    }
  };

  let clock = `${time < 10 && time >= 0 ? `0${time}` : time}:${
    timeSecState < 10 && timeSecState >= 0 ? `0${timeSecState}` : timeSecState
  }`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerID = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timerID);
  });

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="controllerWrapper">
        <div>
          <p id="break-label">Break Length</p>
          <div className="breakController">
            <p
              id="break-increment"
              onClick={() =>
                setBreakState((state) => {
                  if (state < 60) {
                    state += 1;
                    setTimeSecState(0);
                    setTime(state);
                    return state;
                  } else {
                    return state;
                  }
                })
              }
            >
              ↑
            </p>
            <p id="break-length">{breakState}</p>
            <p
              id="break-decrement"
              onClick={() =>
                setBreakState((state) => {
                  if (state > 1) {
                    state -= 1;
                    setTimeSecState(0);
                    setTime(state);
                    return state;
                  } else {
                    return state;
                  }
                })
              }
            >
              ↓
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p id="session-label">Session Length</p>
          <div className="sessionController">
            <p
              id="session-increment"
              onClick={() =>
                setSessionState((state) => {
                  if (state < 60) {
                    state += 1;
                    setTimeSecState(0);
                    setTime(state);
                    return state;
                  } else {
                    return state;
                  }
                })
              }
            >
              ↑
            </p>
            <p id="session-length">{sessionState}</p>
            <p
              id="session-decrement"
              onClick={() =>
                setSessionState((state) => {
                  if (state > 1) {
                    state -= 1;
                    setTimeSecState(0);
                    setTime(state);
                    return state;
                  } else {
                    return state;
                  }
                })
              }
            >
              ↓
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="timerWrapper">
        <p id="timer-label">{breakSession}</p>
        <p id="time-left">{clock}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="startWrapper">
        <button id="start_stop" onClick={() => setPaused(!paused)}>
          Start/Stop
        </button>
        <p id="reset" onClick={() => reset()}>
          Reset
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Comment: the problem was setPaused(!paused)
solution: setPaused(false)